# Проверьте, пожалуйста, сочинение)

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, запятые

В романе Льва Толстого «Война и мир» одной из главных тем являются духовные искания Андрея Болконского и Пьера Безухова. В нём мы видим становление человеческой личности, развитие определённых нравственных качеств героев. Толстой показывает всю глубину русской души и её самые завораживающие качества.
В центре сюжета перед нами предстают лучшие друзья: Андрей Болконский и Пьер Безухов. Дружба – единственное, что их объединяет. Их мысли и чувства рознятся. Андрей, ищущий славы и подвигов, честолюбивый и потерянный в круговороте жизни. Пьер же мягкий, застенчивый, неуклюжий и по-своему простой. Он не ищет выгоды в других людях, как многие персонажи романа. Пытается постигнуть смысл жизни и цель своего пребывания в ней. Многие положительные качества усложняют его жизнь в обществе.
Из-за мягкости и уступчивости своего характера Пьер оказывается женатым на Элен, которая приносит ему только боль, ложь и страдания. Его восприимчивая душа оказывается в клетке заговоров и сплетен, возникающих в результате стараний Элен.
Пьер оставляет свои попытки на счастливую семейную жизнь и дав волю Элен, вступает в ряды масонов. Своей целью он видит строительство мира, которое проповедывают ему члены ложи. Они оплетают разум Безухова, заставляя его ещё больше погружаться в себя с осознанием того что он никому не нужен. Его стремление помогать и жить для других оказывается никому не нужным.
Значительные изменения в Пьере происходят во время нахождения его на войне. Полностью меняет его взгляды на жизнь пребывание во французском плену. Там он знакомится со своим будущим духовным наставником Платоном Каратаевым, который заставляет его взглянуть на мир и на человечество с иной стороны. В итоге после всех испытаний Пьеру открывается совсем иной и новый для него смысл жизни. Его духовным метаниям наступает конец.
В результате своих исканий Андрей освобождается от эгоизма и честолюбия, что преследовали его. И уже перед смертью к нему приходит осознания того, что он должен нести любовь и свет в эту жизнь. Отправившись в первый раз на войну, он покидает свою жену, которая в скором времени умирает при родах. Его ещё долго мучила вина за его холодное отношение к жене. И его воспоминания о том, как он лежал в поле, раненый, смотрящий в небо, осознающий ненужность смерти, которая прошла по полю Аустерлица, его ещё долго не покидали.
Через какое-то время он встречает Наташу Ростову и влюбляется в неё. Он впервые испытывает такие чистые и светлые чувства. С Наташей Андрей понимает, что ещё никогда не испытывал любви. Но, не выдержав долгой разлуки с Болконским, Наташа влюбляется в другого и предаёт Андрея. Болконский не может простить предательства своей избранницы.
И Андрей вновь отправляется на войну, но уже смотрит на всё другими глазами. Он становится ближе к народу и не ищет славы.
После получения смертельной раны, он видит всех своих близких, а также Наташу Ростову, которая беспрерывно о нем заботится. Он понимает, что всё же любит Наташу и именно любовь не дала ему умереть. Но спустя какое-то время он понимает, что смерть — это не конец, а освобождение. Он уже не боится, а ждёт её. В последние минуты жизни Андрей воспринимает всё как освобождение своей уставшей души от долгих и мучительных исканий.

Comment: Мы не проверяем сочинения. См. Справку.